# Invoke window loaded event for owner window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have windows1 and windows2, windows1 owned windows2

```
_windows2 = new Windows2();
_windows2.Owner = this; // this=windows1
_windows2.Show();
this.Hide();
```

When closing windows2, I display the window1

```
private void Window2_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Owner.Show();
}
```

But the window1 loaded event does not invoked, I have some calculation that must updates after close window2.

How can I Invoke window1 loaded event after close window2?

Comment: Do you really want to reload window1 or do you just want to do some calculations and show the results? I guess you don't have to reload your window1 when just doing the calculations.

Comment: window1 has Chart view the read the values from ObservableCollection that filled in windows load event

Comment: When you create a method with the "filling logic" you can call it in the windows load event and in your new case without the need to reload the window ;)

Comment: I understand that, But where can I call this method after show window1 ?

Comment: I guess you could do it after `this.Owner.Show()` but it's hard to say without knowing more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move your code to an `Activated` event handler, or call your `Loaded` event handler when the `Activated` event occurs:

```
int i = 0;
this.Activated += (ss, ee) =>
{
    if (i++ == 0) //not the first time...
        OnLoaded(this, EventArgs.Empty);
};
```

If you don't want to execute your code when switch between applications or windows, you might as well put the code directly in the `Window2_Closed` event handler:

```
private void Window2_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Owner.Show();
    OnLoaded(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Comment: Activated is not good, because you get run your OnLoaded(..) also on switch between the applications.

Comment: If that's an issue, you might as well put the code directly in the Window2_Closed event handler. I edited my answer to clarify this.

Comment: Thanks mm8 for your assist.